# How do I get each attribute on its own line when serializing XML?

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-formatting

I am writing config data to an XML file. But the XML looks very unstructured or how to say

```
<Configuration>
  <Ftp Host="LOCALHOST" Port="21"/>
  <Pop3 Host="LOCALHOST" Port="110" Interval="30000"/>
  <Smtp Host="LOCALHOST" Port="25"/>
</Configuration>
```

I would like it to look like

```
<Configuration>
  <Ftp 
        Host="LOCALHOST" 
        Port="21"
    />
  <Pop3 
        Host="LOCALHOST" 
        Port="110" 
        Interval="30000"
    />
  <Smtp 
        Host="LOCALHOST" 
        Port="25"
    />
</Configuration>
```

Is that possible in any way
Here is a snippet of my Delphi code for this. I have functions/procedure for all types but just showing 2 here

```
constructor TConnXml.Create(const FileName: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fConfigfile     := FileName;
  fXMLDoc         := TXMLDocument.Create(Application);
  fXMLDoc.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];
  if FileExists(fConfigfile) then
    fXMLDoc.LoadFromFile(fConfigfile)
  else
    begin
      fXMLDoc.Active := True;
      fXMLDoc.AddChild('Configuration');
      fXMLDoc.SaveToFile(fConfigfile);
    end;
end;

constructor TConnXml.Create;
begin
  Create(SettingsFileBuild);
end;

function TConnXml.ReadString(const Section, Key, Default: string): string;
var
  Node: IXMLNode;
begin
  Node := fXMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode(Section);
  if Assigned(Node) and Node.HasAttribute(Key) then
    Result := Node.Attributes[Key]
  else
    Result := Default;
end;

procedure TConnXml.WriteString(const Section, Key, Value: string);
var
  Node: IXMLNode;
begin
  if ReadString(Section, Key, '') = Value then
    Exit;
  Node := fXMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode(Section);
  if not Assigned(Node) then
    Node := fXMLDoc.DocumentElement.AddChild(Section);
  Node.Attributes[Key] := Value;
  fModified := True;
  Save;
end;

procedure TConnXml.Save;
begin
  if not fModified then
    Exit;
  if fBackup then
    CopyFile(PChar(fConfigfile), PChar(fConfigfile + '.bak'), False);
  fXMLDoc.Active := True;
  fXMLDoc.SaveToFile(fConfigfile);
  fModified := False;
end;

function TConnXml.ReadBoolean(const Section, Key: string; Default: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Boolean(ReadInteger(Section, Key, Integer(Default)));
end;

procedure TConnXml.WriteBoolean(const Section, Key: string; Value: Boolean);
begin
  WriteInteger(Section, Key, Integer(Value));
end;
```

Comment: xml's main purpose is NOT to be readable by humans. it's for machine-machine communication. your output is the "correct" formated XML-Output as is should be. why do you need an other appearance ? If you realy want it to "look" other than xml you have to writer your own XmlWriter or you should change to an other format.

Comment: Consider using [TIniFile](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/tinifile.htm) instead. It will be much less likely that the person editing the settings in the `.ini` file structure will get it wrong, whereas XML is *syntax-heavy*.

Comment: Make it look nicer by using YAML instead

Comment: It looks like perfectly well-formed XML, with standard formatting (even with special indentations to make it human-readable). You could associate an XSL(T) stylesheet to it, converting it to a nice HTML representation, so it looks neat in a browser. But that's probably overkill.

Comment: You already use option doNodeAutoIndent and it makes XML readable. It is more than enough.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan   I don't know YAML but what I see on Wikipedia about it looks nice.  I will have to look for some Delphi code that can handle it

Comment: >all   I was just wondering if the XML could be more human readable if someone should want to edit the setting of my software.

Comment: @OZ8HP - the example you show is quite readable. Don't sweat over it.

Comment: @Leonardo, it is readable because it is small, if it grows all that attributes make it hard to read. I only use attributes when neccessary in my configuration files.

Comment: You won't find any Delphi code for YAML, I think. The only such code is, I think, my own wrapper of libyaml but that's not shareable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan   OK - maybe in a near future there will be code for it :-)

Comment: @Runner - agree, but every time I find myself digging in XML code I just use the *Find* feature of my editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you produce this XML and it is for configuration purposes, then making it more readable has its purpose. I use XML for configuration a lot and I only use attributes when really applicable.

I would write it like this:

```
<Configuration>
  <Ftp> 
    <Host>LOCALHOST</Host> 
    <Port>25</Port>
  </Ftp>
  <Pop3> 
    <Host>LOCALHOST/<Host> 
    <Port>110</Port>
    <Interval>30000</Interval>
  </Pop>
  <Smtp> 
    <Host>LOCALHOST</Host> 
    <Port>25</Port>
  </Smtp>
</Configuration>
```

Using some other format, then XML, is also a solution. But if you stick to XML then my answer is one way to organize XML in a human readable fasion. Also if you avoid attributes then conversion to JSON for instance is very simple.

Even if XML is bloated with markup I find it readable if structured well. And although it was meant for computer data exchange I find it very good for configuration files. YAML looks fine, but for me it lacks that explicit structure :)

**Update:**

Due to the request for the code I updated the answer with additional info. To get XML like mine bellow, all you have to do is change one procedure. On the other hand this is basic XML handling so I advise you to learn it.

```
function TConnXml.ReadString(const Section, Key, Default: string): string;
var
  Node: IXMLNode;
  Child: IXMLNode;
begin
  Node := fXMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode(Section);

  if not Assigned(Node) then 
  begin
    Result := Default;
    Exit;
  end;

  Child:= Node.FindNode(Key);

  if not Assigned(Child) then 
  begin
    Result := Default;
    Exit;
  end;

  Result := Child.Text;
end;

procedure TConnXml.WriteString(const Section, Key, Value: string);
var
  Node: IXMLNode;
  Child: IXMLNode;
begin
  if ReadString(Section, Key, '') = Value then
    Exit;

  Node := fXMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode(Section);

  if not Assigned(Node) then
    Node := fXMLDoc.DocumentElement.AddChild(Section);

  Child:= Node.ChildNodes.FindNode(Key);

  if not Assigned(Child) then
    Child:= Node.AddChild(Key);

  Child.Text := Value;
  fModified := True;
  Save;
end;
```

I wrote it without testing so there may be some mistakes in it, but that is the code you should use.

Comment: YAML lacks structure?!!

Comment: I wrote that to fast David. I guess there is nothing wrong with YAML. I am just used to XML explicit tagging (with < and > chars) and I actually navigate faster because of that. But that is just me, I am well aware that YAML is not as bloated as XML.

Comment: @Runner   it is exact what I was hoping to have my file look like. But I haven't figured out how to do it yet.  If someone has some sample code, I would love to have a look.

Comment: @Runner  That made the config file look at least 100% more readable to the human eye